# Replace html markup in strings

Tags: php, html, regex, string, str-replace

How can I replace html elements in strings which have mixed content such as:

```
$str = "Find the &nbsp; element in this string";
```

I'd like to clear all &nbsp ; elements in the string. So, I tried:

```
str_replace("&nbsp;", " ", $str);
```

I know that &nbsp ; is space and renders as empty space, however there is a specific reason I need to do that related to other DB operations i have.

If str_replace doesn't work for HTML tags, should I use regular expressions?

Comment: Are you sure you're the first person who asked this question ever? C'mon, show some research effort, man.

Comment: its working, check it out: http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/ui4p-v2a1

Comment: Have a look, [it is all working](https://ideone.com/mcRc6G).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that it should be &amp;nbsp; rather than &nbsp;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = htmlentities($string, null, 'utf-8');
$str = str_replace("&nbsp;", "", $str);
```

Comment: Thanks, however it doesn't work. I did: $string = "this is the new &nbsp; snippet";

$str1 = htmlentities($string, null, 'utf-8');
$str2 = str_replace("&nbsp;", "REPLACEMENT", $str1);

echo $str1;

echo $str2;

Comment: $str2 produces: this is the new &nbsp; snippet

Comment: can't say why it's not working

Comment: It should be &amp;nbsp;  not &nbsp